Python cloud function restarts again and again in the GCP *** Edit: potentially driven by pub/sub not acknowledged, how to acknowledge directy in code
*** Edit: looks like the issue could come from the Pub/sub cloud scheduler... Any idea how to prevent it from resending a message after 10 minutes? I can't find the set-up in the scheduler options ***
*** Edit 2: ok, the pub/sub cloud scheduler never receives the confirmation after 10 minutes. Big question: is there any piece of code to send confirmation/Acknowledgment message right after the pub/sub is first sent, so we don't have to worry about it anymore? ***
I've written a Cloud Function 2nd gen in the GCP to perform a few POST calls to Shopify (basically, update stocks).
The function runs well, I've got my time.sleep not to send too much calls to Shopify.
Thing is, it runs, and then after 10 minutes, start running again, and I don't understand why as it should just stop.
It is triggered by a Cloud scheduler, once a day at night, in Europe West 3 Frankfurt. I've let the instances set-up to default, with no retry (no retry on the Scheduler either), just put 3600sec to my function.
Any one with an idea of what could happen here? I've looked at doc + thousands of questions, but I can't manage to find one that is related. I've added the return 1 to all def, the time.sleep to the post to avoid errors, made sure it run in less than 10 minutes, put 3600 seconds?
Here's a dummy of the code I've written:
import requests
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import storage
import time
import json
from google.cloud import bigquery

  
def stock_to_shopify():


  client=bigquery.Client()
  query= """
      SELECT * FROM `XXX.YYY.ZZZ` ORDER BY 1,2,3 LIMIT 400
  """
  query_job = client.query(query)

  headers = {
    'X-Shopify-Access-Token': 'XXX',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }

  for stock_to_shopify in query_job:
    json_data = {
    'location_id': stock_to_shopify[0],
    'inventory_item_id': stock_to_shopify[1],
    'available': stock_to_shopify[2],
    }

    response = requests.post(
      'https://XXX.myshopify.com/admin/api/2024-04/inventory_levels/set.json',
      headers=headers,
      json=json_data,
    )
    time.sleep(1)

    print(response.text)

  return 1


def main(data,context):
  stock_to_shopify()
  print("run ok")
  return 1

Maestro
Played with the instance numbers, but went back to default
Added 3600s for my function to run
Added return 1 on all def

After some tests, it also looks that it starts running again after 10 minutes, somehow a new instance goes live with the same code running, no idea why :/

If you return a 200 HTTP code before the Deleviry Ack deadlin of PubSUb subscribtion, it should work. Not sure to catch your issuehere.

Thanks for that, and sorry, my question is unclear (as I don't understnad totally where the problem comes from...). Then, the question becomes, how can I return a 200 HTTP so it gets caught by the corresponding pub/sub?

change your return 1, to return 1,200

OK, makes sense. And so, assuming I've got several messages from several pub/sub scheduler, it will only disable the corresponding one? Merci beaucoup Guillaume, this is awesome!

And now, the big question: what happens in function finishes after the delivery ack deadline? I found where, but I cannot update it to more than 10 minutes :/

Before going in the wrong way, let's talk about want do you want to achieve: Do you want to run a job on a message and process it asynchronously? And does this processing take more than 10 minutes?

Many thanks for the follow-up :) Objective: use a Cloud Scheduler pub/sub message push to launch every day at XX:XX a Python Cloud Function. Processing does take > than 10mins, hence the issue (after 10min, no return 200 yet, message not acknowledged, cloud function relaunched -> problems). My workaround: Cloud scheduler + cloud function + another cloud function that returns 200 immediatly. This way, no re-launch, main function can run more than 10min and finish quietly. I've seen other possible set-up with workflows and more. Now, all hears to do it better :) Thanks!

PubSub is useless in that case. Use Cloud Scheduler to Cloud Functions. Cloud Scheduler timeout is 30 minutes, not 10, so you can leverage the "retry" feature of Cloud Scheduler like that. If it's longer than 30 minutes, I recommend to use Scheduler + Cloud Run Jobs instead of Cloud Function. It's designed for long and asynchronous processing.

ok, thanks for that, I'm going to investigate in that direction! But I do have a retry after 10 minutes with Cloud Scheduler push, so I do think there is a 10 minutes limit somewhere, if not I don't get why a new instance starts after 10min. But as suggested, moving to Cloud Run Jobs might be better, thanks!

I don't know your ack deadline on your current subscription. I guess it's 10 minutes. Because the PubSub subscription do not receive the ack after 10 minutes (timeout), a new message is delivered

That's correct, and I don't see the option to change it in the interface (or maybe it can be done through the console)? Many many thanks! Btw, my answer is correct right? The second cloud function will indeed ack the subscription for all?

I didn't want to jump into this!! But.... In fact, when you send a response with Cloud Functions, the functions end (in reality, the CPU is throttled and no processing is possible on the function). By the way, if you ack immediately the PubSub message, you won't have a new invocation in 10 minutes, but your cloud function won't be able to perform processing because of "no cpu available". That's why, either you call a new function in fire and forget mode, or you use a job service like Cloud Run job, or Cloud Batch.

Noted, many thanks for the follow-up! Removing my answer then as it is far from being accurate nor helpful for the community ^^
